# MSSQL DateTime default is GetDate() doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, getdate

I have a Table which was declared to receive `GetDate()` by default,
the thing i get **invalid character value for cast specification**.

On most of our servers we didn't got this error, but on one server we got this error.

I solved this issue by creating a trigger that calls a function that updates the inserted record with  `GetDate()`.

I would like to hear your opinion  what could possibly go  wrong.

```
MSSQL 2008 x64 r2. windows server 2008 R2 datacenter.
```

Comment: Could you post complete CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: this show your insert data type is not valid on any column or if it is in date datatype, then format is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a cast error then the datatype of the column is not DateTime. You would have to use an explicit CAST instead, or change the datatype of the column.